# Remove IIFE wrapper from Javascript

Tags: javascript, minify

I'm working on a build system for my Ember.js project and I'm trying to remove the IIFE from certain Javascript files. Most of my files comes out looking like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    App.FooBarController = Ember.Controller.extend({});
})();
```

I wrap every file in an IIFE because it allows me to more easily declare strict mode. It's also a good habit to get into, I think, because it acts as a safety wrapper. However, about 3/4 of my files don't contain any extra variables in the IIFE, just the Ember component that gets put into the `App` namespace. This means that when I'm concatenating files, I can safely remove the IIFE and save about 17 characters. (Not a huge deal, but every byte counts, right?)

So is there any kind of library or compiler that would be able to do this for me? Specifically, detect when it is and isn't safe to remove the IIFE? Or is that beyond the scope of static analysis?

Comment: "Or is that beyond the scope of static analysis" -- I think you answered your own question :). You can maybe automate it in your text editor with search-replace.

Comment: I just figured that it doesn't hurt to ask. The Javascript community is a resourceful bunch. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this using the node libraries `falafel` and `escodegen`.

Basically you'd create a build script that uses falafel to process the source code. You'd need to figure out the top-level IIFE, and then whether there are any variables directly inside it or such.

It might not be necessary to use escodegen as you might be able to get away just clearing the nodes instead of having to generate new JS code.

In any case, I don't think there's any other way of doing this besides writing a custom analyzer like this.